# How to have all options of some menu on the same line?

Tags: 8, navigation

In the [mayo](https://www.drupal.org/project/mayo) theme I use for my site, I have a footer menu.
By default, the options of this menu are displayed vertically:
[image]

I'd like to have the options displayed horizontally.
How can I do that?

Comment: CSS would be the simplest way, if they are output in a single list. You’d add the display inline property.

Comment: Got that! But how to do it only in that portion of the site (and not in User's account menu for example)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTML code for the menu was:

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li> <a href="/contact">Contact</a> </li>
    <li> <a href="/faq">FAQ</a> </li>
</ul>
```

In the CSS file of my theme, I found `ul.menu` but also `ul.inline`.
Once replaced .menu by .inline in my browser inspector, I had what I expected.
So I digged - a lot - in Twig debug (never could make work either `{{ dump(something) }}` or `{{ kint(something) }}` probably because of memory issues).
I finally used

```
<!-- FILE NAME SUGGESTIONS:
   * menu--footer.html.twig
   x menu.html.twig
-->
```

I duplicated `menu.html.twig` into `menu--footer.html.twig` and replaced
`<ul{{ attributes.addClass('menu') }}>`
by
`<ul{{ attributes.addClass('inline') }}>`
and voilà !
[image]